# Jquery Ajax - Durante o envio - mostrar data retorno em tempo real

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, foreach

quero que o usuário possa acompanhar o andamento de cada envio em uma aplicação. Tenho de um lado, o envio via ajax, e com php realizo um foreach para envio em lote. Por exemplo, selecione o id 1,2,3,5,7, e pressiono enviar. Quero q mostre na tela em tempo real, "enviando id1"...."enviando id2", cada um no seu respectivo momento... Podemos pensar em 2 estagios a serem exibidos: Enviando id2...id2 enviado..e assim por diante.. Enviando id3... id3 enviado. Como isso está em um foreach, ocorrerá em lote sucessivamente até acabar todos que o usuario selecionar.

Tentei assim:

```
$("form").submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "arquivo-foreach.php",
        data: dados,
        beforeSend: function(data){
            $(".box").html(data);
        },
        success: function( data ){
            $(".box").html(data);
        }//end success
    });//end method
    return false;
});//end submit
```

Consigo o resultado de todos os enviados depois que todo processo se conclui, mas não aparece um de cada vez enquanto está sendo enviado.. Alguém saberia como?

Comment: Acredito que se você quer esse controle item a item deveria fazer um POST para cada dado... Outra forma seria através de socket, mas é muito mais trabalho. Ou ainda criar um outro método só para retornar esses status e ficar consultando em um intervalo que você define.

Comment: Mas como ficaria isso no código? Porque tentei com o beforeSend da forma que postei, e o resultado aparece somente no Success.. então gostaria de saber como funcionaria para que cada um fosse mostrado em seu respectivo tempo...

Comment: Algum tipo de uso com console.log... alguma idéia?

Comment: Tentei com console.log.. mas não aparece na tela..